# A simpler way to calculate grouped percentages in a Spark dataframe?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Given the following dataframe:

```python
df = sc.parallelize([
    ('2017-05-21', 'a'),
    ('2017-05-21', 'c'),
    ('2017-05-22', 'b'),
    ('2017-05-22', 'c'),
    ('2017-05-23', 'a'),
    ('2017-05-23', 'b'),
    ('2017-05-23', 'c'),
    ('2017-05-23', 'c'),
]).toDF(['date', 'foo'])
```

I would like to get the daily percentages of `foo == a`:

```
+----------+----------+
|      date|percentage|
+----------+----------+
|2017-05-21|       0.5|
|2017-05-22|       0.0|
|2017-05-23|      0.25|
+----------+----------+
```

This is what I came up with:

```
df.withColumn('foo_a', df.foo == 'a')
  .groupby('date')
  .agg((func.sum(col('foo_a').cast('integer'))/func.count('*')).alias('percentage'))
  .sort('date')
```

This works, but I feel like there should be an easier way. Specifically, is there an aggregate function for counting the occurrences of a certain value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mean` / `avg` combined with `when`:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import avg, col, when

df.groupBy("date").agg(avg(when(col("foo") == "a", 1).otherwise(0)))
```

or `cast`:

```
df.groupBy("date").agg(avg((col("foo") == "a").cast("integer")))
```

is all you need.